# Pulling prior year data

Tags: ms-access

I am working on a query to pull all turnover in the past calendar year that is going to be used daily. Rather than going in and having to change the date each time I would just like to be able to run the query and have it automatically only pull the last 365 days worth of data. The code  itself looks like:

```
SELECT O867IA_VJOBHST.SYS_EMP_ID_NR, O867IA_VJOBHST.REC_EFF_STT_DT, O867IA_VJOBHST.EMP_ACN_TYP_CD
FROM O867IA_VJOBHST
WHERE (((O867IA_VJOBHST.EMP_ACN_TYP_CD)="HIR"));
```

Where the REC_EFF_STT_DT is the date the ACN_TYP_CD occurred, in this case when they were HIR (Hired)

Any Ideas?

Comment: In your question you talk about a "calendar year", which runs Jan 1 to Dec 31. Then you talk about pulling a rolling 365 days. Which one are you actually trying to achieve?  And how different is this question from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705655/using-the-now-function-in-access

Answer (score 1):

Access SQL provides `Date()` and `DateAdd()` functions.  You can work out what you need from those functions in the Immediate window ...

```vb
? Date()
9/9/2013 
? DateAdd("d", -365, Date())
9/9/2012
```

Then you can filter `REC_EFF_STT_DT` on the same date range in a query like this ...

```sql
SELECT o.SYS_EMP_ID_NR, o.REC_EFF_STT_DT, o.EMP_ACN_TYP_CD
FROM O867IA_VJOBHST AS o
WHERE
    o.REC_EFF_STT_DT BETWEEN DateAdd('d', -365, Date()) AND Date();
```